# Google Analytics | Submit Data

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I can't seem to find any info on how to do this but basically on submit I need to send either the mobile number the user inputted or the email not both, just one or the other.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Friday Deals', 'Music and Sports', '[48r6KevWQkGNIgjRc95owg or xwPuPgV9D0ifMwjRc95swg]']);
```

In the array you will see the first name ( This is the mobile number name ) the second is the email name.

I am using the name attribute on the inputs.

Is this correct? How can I test to see if this is working in Chrome?

Comment: To debug in Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Sending personal data (like emails or phone numbers) to Google Analytics is against their [Terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) (Section 7):

> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service
>   to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an
>   individual (such as a name, email address or billing information), or
>   other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by
>   Google.

Talking generally, if you really want to register only one data point of the two potentially available, it should be done server-side (the exact code depends obviously on what system and language are you using) and sent the result as a parameter to Google Analytics .

Alternatively, you could obviously register two data points at the same time (not just one or the other) using [two parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=es#SettingUpEventTracking). You can put for example one as the "action" parameter and the other as the "label" parameter, like in this example

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Friday Deals', 'DATA1', 'DATA2']);
```

Or use the other optional parameter "value" to register a number. For example:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Friday Deals', 'Music and Sports', 'DATA1', '54646465']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @migueltic. What I'm wondering is if I pass in the name attribute on my element and do as above - would this work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by the name attribute, but I guess it should work. Anyway, you can try it pretty easily with the Real Time reports in Google Analytics. It now includes a report for watching events in real time, including their parameters (category, action and label).

Comment: name attribute on the input...<input name="phone-number" type="text" />